# C# winform dynamically created textboxes event (textChanged ) isn't fired

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I am working on windows form ,I am creating textboxes on "Add more" button so I want to get the value of text changed event of every textbox.

Here's my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   // I created text box wc
   TextBox wc = new TextBox();

   // now bind it with textchanged event
   wc.TextChanged += wc_TextChanged;
  }
    void wc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var box = (TextBox)sender;
        label1.Text = box.Text;

    }
```

I have tried this but on text change of every box its not fired,

Thanks

Comment: If you don't add them to your form you don't even see them

Comment: i have added them on the form , have not mentioned the code for that

Comment: Try putting a `MessageBox.Show()` in your `TextChanged` event to be sure it is, indeed, never hitting that method, or set a debugger breakpoint and make sure its hitting it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to your `form` as well:

```
// I created text box wc
TextBox wc = new TextBox();

// now bind it with textchanged event
wc.TextChanged += wc_TextChanged;

this.Controls.Add(wc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the event and the textboxes

```
private TextBox wc;
Form()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     wc = new TextBox();
     wc.TextChanged += wc_TextChanged;
     wc.Visible = false;
     Controls.Add(wc);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     wc.Visible = true;
}
```

Controls should be added always, you should only control the visibility of the controls !

Comment: @hasanfarooq I make the edit check it, even explain it.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine for me

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox wc = new TextBox();

        this.Controls.Add(wc);

        wc.TextChanged+=wc_TextChanged;

    }

    void wc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var box = (TextBox)sender;
        MessageBox.Show("TEXT CHANGED");

    }
```